# I can't use a "kill" process in my code. (its underlined with red)

Tags: c#

I want to press a button, and when the button is activated, to close the application I desire. For example if I open notepad, I want to press a button and close notepad. But for some reason, I cannot use the `kill` or `close` command as it underlines it with red. I am building this application in C#. Here is the code.

```
public EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs> sRecognized { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        
    void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text == "alice present")
        {
            SoundPlayer sndPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Ai.Properties.Resources.My_name_is_A_L_I_C_E);
            sndPlayer.Play();
        }

        if (e.Result.Text == "open notepad")
        {
            Process notepad = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        }

        if (e.Result.Text == "close notepad")
        {
            BtnN.PerformClick();
        }
    }
     private void BtnN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process notepad = Process.Kill("notepad.exe");
    }
```

Comment: `Kill` is an instance method, you're trying to invoke it statically. Find the instance of "notepad.exe" that you wish to kill, create a Process out of it and kill that.

Comment: Also, please put effort into formatting your code online so it is readable. You have too much whitespace.

Comment: Do you enjoy reading your own post?

Comment: If that line of code would work, which of the 3 running processes of "notepad.exe" do you expect to be killed?

Comment: @tchelidze thanks for your reply. I tried putting that code in the BtnN_click void and it wouldnt close the notepad process. Any idea why?

Comment: @DenverGown are you getting any error ?

Comment: @tchelidze no but it wont close notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make it very simple. Create a `Process` field and use it everywhere:

```
private Process pNotepad;   //Process field

void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Text == "alice present")
    {
        SoundPlayer sndPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Ai.Properties.Resources.My_name_is_A_L_I_C_E);
        sndPlayer.Play();
    }

    if (e.Result.Text == "open notepad")
    {
        //starting Process "notepad"
        pNotepad = new Process();
        pNotepad.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        pNotepad.Start();
    }

    if (e.Result.Text == "close notepad")
    {
        BtnN.PerformClick();
    }
}

private void BtnN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //kill process if it is running
    if(pNotepad != null && pNotepad.HasExited == false)
        pNotepad.Kill();
}
```

Comment: It says this next to the pNotepad.startinfor.filename = "notepad.exe" Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: There should not be any exception, I forgot a line there. Try again. Copy the complete code snippet I have posted.

Comment: Thank you so so so much! Honestly!

Answer (score -1):

As it was mentioned in comments, `Process.Kill` is instance method, not static method, so you need to have instance of `Process` class in order to call `Kill` method. 
 
You should also consider that process name is not Unique identifier for process, since there can be more that one process with the same name. 
After that, if you are want to all the processes based on name, you can use following code.

```
 public static void KillProcess(string processName)
 {
   var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

   foreach (var proc in process)
     proc.Kill();
 }
```

As you create new process on your own, you can store that process Id in a static variable

```
 ...
public static int OpenedProcessId;
...
Process notepad = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
OpenedProcessId = process.Id;
...
```

(which is Unique identifier) and use that to kill that specific process with following code.

```
public static bool KillProcess(int processId)
{
  try
  {
    var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
    process.Kill();
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
}
```

Comment: If we need an instance, why not simply remember the instance of `Process` that was created when starting the process? For the sake of the user of the application, never suggest such a thing as an answer. This is dangerous! If I have 5 Notepads open and 1 is started by the app, you'll kill 6 processes and all my work in 5 processes is lost!

Comment: @ThomasWeller thanks thomas for suggestion, Sure we can. let me just modify my answer so that it will be more suitable for current question Context.

Comment: @ThomasWeller thomas, i've already mentioned what you are warning about, please fully read my answer, not just code.

Comment: After using the following code, notepad opens, but does not close.

Comment: @DenverGown Do you have privileges to kill that process?

Comment: So does all those 3 snips of code go in order? sorry...

Comment: Also, where do i add this code? because i need it to activate once i have pressed the button. Can i put a void in a void?

Comment: @DenverGown In this case , you will only need second and third code samples. 1. Declare `public static int OpenedProcessId;` Field in your `Form1` class. 2. When you will create new process, Assign `process.Id` to `OpenedProcessId` variable. 3. In `BtnN_Click` method, call `KillProcess` method and pass `OpenedProcessId` variable as argument.

Comment: Where is my form1 class?

Comment: oops never mind hold on

Comment: How do i assign process.id to openedprocessid?

Comment: @DenverGown In `sRecognize_SpeechRecognized` method, after you `Start` new process,  write following `OpenedProcessId = notepad.Id;`

Comment: Is this in the right place? it has a redline udnerneath the Id.
if
            
            (e.Result.Text == "open notepad")

            {
                Process notepad = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
                OpenedProcessId = process.Id;

Comment: @DenverGown you variable name is `notepad`. so replace following line `OpenedProcessId = process.Id;` with `OpenedProcessId = notepad.Id;`

Comment: Ok got step 1 and 2 done. I dont understand step 3 though.

Comment: @DenverGown what you did not understand ?

Comment: how to call "killProcess" method and pass "openedProcessId" variable as argument.

Comment: @DenverGown write following `BtnN_Click` method. `private void BtnN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OpenedProcessId  != 0)
       KillProcess(OpenedProcessId);   
}`

Comment: okay my code for step 2 has gone and cant remember it :/ undo wont work :/

Comment: Ok i got it working thank you :)

Comment: @DenverGown glad if helped.